# how to update and refresh the view immediately after clicking the save button

Tags: swift, swiftui, refresh, updates

This page has already can save the new information but it has to exit the page to the last page then this page can show up the new information after entering this page again.The main question is I want to update and refresh the information immediately after clicking the save button.
But I don't know how to do it.

The main page I talk about is here

```
import SwiftUI

struct profile3: View {
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var instagram = ""
    @State private var age = ""
    @State private var birth = ""
    @State private var habit = ""
    @State private var live = ""
    @State private var head = ""
    @ObservedObject var httpClient = HTTPUser()
    
   //let user: UserLogin
    
    private func newPer(){
        let new = self.httpClient.per
        for value in new!{
            let per = Per(id:value.id,name: name, account: instagram, picture: head, age: age, birth: birth, city: live, hobby: habit, user: value.user)
            httpClient.newPer(per: per){success in
                
                }
            }
        }

 
    private func get(){
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        guard let token = defaults.string(forKey: "value") else {
            return
        }
        httpClient.getper(value: token)
    }
    

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            
            
            ZStack{
                Image("background")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                    VStack{
                        Profile1Image(imageName:"profileboy")
                            
                            .padding()
                        Form{
                            Section(header: Text("information")){
                                List(self.httpClient.per ?? [Per](),id: \.id){ person in
                                    VStack {
                                        TextField("name : \(person.name!)", text: $name)
                                        TextField("Instagram : \(person.account!)",text: $instagram)
                                        TextField("pic : \(person.picture!)",text: $head)
                                        TextField("age : \(person.age!)",text: $age)
                                        TextField("birth : \(person.birth!)",text: $birth)
                                        TextField(city : \(person.city!)",text: $live)
                                        TextField("hobby : \(person.hobby!)",text: $habit)
                                    }
                                    
                                    
                                }
                                
                                
                            }.onAppear(perform: {
                                self.get()
                            })
                        }
                    }.toolbar {
                        
                        Button("Save"){
                            self.newPer()
                            //self.savePer()
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct profile3_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        profile3()
    }
}
struct Profile1Image: View {
    var imageName: String
    var body: some View{
        Image(uiImage:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "profileboy"))
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 250,height: 250)
            .clipShape(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Circle()/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}
```

Comment: Although it is not clear what information you want to "update", I would recommend you use "ObservableObject" to capture the updates. This will then refresh the views when there is a change. You will have to study how to use and pass the ObservableObject around your views.

Comment: Button("Save"){
                            self.newPer()
                        }    I can save the information about the user but it can't show up immediately when I click the button.I have no idea how to use it.Thanks for your answering!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you want to show and where you are trying to show it. I cannot see where in your code you are showing this.

Comment: OK!My Modes has a Per.swift  and here is it!I want to show the new name, account,age etc. on the profile3.  thank you! import Foundation

struct Per: Codable{
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var account: String?
    var picture: String?
    var age: String?
    var birth: String?
    var city: String?
    var hobby: String?
    var user: UserLogin?